# How to select groups which has only the values we want and not select it if it also has other values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | cod | 2 |
| A | buy | 34 |
| A | cod | 4 |
| B | cod | 44 |
| B | F | 23 |
| C | thk | 45 |
| C | cod | 33 |
| C | F | 31 |
| D | cod | 22 |

In this table for example, I want those groups of id which has 'code' column value as ONLY cod or F. so query should return values of id = B and nothing else. ( Not even values with id = C because id=C also has 'thk' in code ,  not even id= D, and output should have ids with ONLY the mentioned two values)

expected output

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | cod | 44 |
| B | F | 23 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result. A [mcve], you know.-

Comment: which sql are you using ?

Comment: MS sql server, just updated the tag

Comment: What about C, that has cod and F?

Comment: C also has thk, hence it should not be present in output

Comment: @q74hyu_oi please check the solution below and confirm if it is working for you

Comment: From the answers I gather that your request is not completely clear. As I understand it, you would return all cod and F rows as long as there is no non-cod/F row for the id in the table. I think this is quite clear from how you have described the task, Others, however, think an ID must have at least one cod row and one F row in order to get selected. Maybe you should clarify this, add a row like D|cod|22 to the sample table and show whether you expect this in the results or not.

Answer (score 1):

One of approaches with nested query

```
SELECT ID,Code, value FROM (
    select ID, Code,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM TableA a where Code = 'cod' and a.ID = TableA.ID) Cod,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM TableA a where Code = 'F' and a.ID = TableA.ID) F,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM TableA a where Code not in ('F','cod') and a.ID = TableA.ID) Other,
        Value
    from TableA 
) SOURCE
WHERE Cod <> 0 AND F <> 0 and Other = 0
```

Comment: You don't need nested queries for the counting. You can use window functions (`COUNT OVER`) instead: `select id, code, count(case when code = 'cod' then 1 end) over (partition by id) as cod, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You want all rows for the ID of which **not exists** a forbidden row:

```
select id, code, value
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable forbidden_row
  where forbidden_row.id = mytable.id
  and forbidden_row.code not in ('cod', 'F')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with main as (
select *, count(id) over(partition by id order by id) as total_rows
from sample
), next_and_before as (
select *,
COALESCE(lag(code) over(partition by id order by id),lead(code) over(partition by id order by id)) as before_next
from main where total_rows <= 2 
)
select * from next_and_before 
where lower(trim(concat(code,before_next)))in('codf','fcod','cod','f')
```

Its a bit of hacky solution:

- first you are filtering out all the rows that have less than or equal to 2 rows, since there could be cases where you only have one row per id with a code value = 'f' or 'cod', if you don't want that then simply change the last part to: `in ('codf','fcod')`
- then out of two rows, you are looking at the next and before value and checking if it contains other than 'f' or 'cod'
- where clause will filter those out if they exist

**Test Results from the link below:**

[Results of sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/MdmmaqqO)

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using CTE. Check this,

```
-- Split the two record category first, then check cod Or F condition.
WITH Count2 AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) = 2
), 
codORF AS (
    SELECT id, code, COUNT(id) FROM YourTable T1 
    LEFT JOIN Count2 T2 On T1.id = T2.id
    WHERE code = 'cod' OR code = 'F'
    GROUP BY id, code
    Having COUNT(id) = 1
)
--  Finally to take all values
SELECT T1.* 
FROM YourTable T1 
INNER JOIN codORF T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```